# Replicating an svg animation

Tags: svg, svg-animate

When this site first loads there’s this animation where there’s a triangle that traces over another triangle.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hlkg9.png)

http://nueuphoria.com/

How would I replicate the same thing?

Where the triangle traces over the other triangle.

Can someone provide a jsfiddle of how it's done.

I found this from the site, but I don't know how to put it together.

https://jsfiddle.net/s2z3xyd8/6/

```html
<div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
<defs>
<style>
.cls-1{fill:none;stroke:#fff;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:4px;}</style>
</defs>
<g id="Слой_2" data-name="Слой 2">
<g id="play">
<path class="cls-1" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83"></path>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just using the common line drawing technique of animating the `stroke-dashoffset`.  The bit you were missing was the @keyframes` definition(s).

```css
.logo-load_w svg path {
  stroke: #08f9ff;
  stroke-dasharray: 150;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1500;
  -webkit-animation: draw 20s infinite linear;
  animation: draw 20s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-load_w">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke:#fff;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:4px;}</style></defs><g id="Слой_2" data-name="Слой 2"><g id="play"><path class="cls-1" d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83"></path></g></g></svg>
</div>
```

The dark triangle in the background is just a second copy of the SVG, with the `stroke` colour set to a different colour.

#### Update

The simplest way to have a darker triangle behind the blue one, is not the way the original site does it.  It is easier just to add a second copy of the triangle into the SVG.  You put it earlier in the SVG, so that it is drawn first.  And make its stroke colour black.

```css
.logo-load_w svg .play {
  stroke: #08f9ff;
  stroke-dasharray: 150;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1500;
  -webkit-animation: draw 20s infinite linear;
  animation: draw 20s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-load_w">

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="80" height="80" viewBox="0 0 47.96 51.66">
    <defs>
      <style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke:#fff;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:4px;}</style>
    </defs>
    <g class="cls-1">
      <path stroke="black"
            d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83"/>
      <path class="play"
            d="M2,25.83V4.11A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,5.13,2.27L44.88,24.45a2.11,2.11,0,0,1,0,3.7L5.1,49.41A2.11,2.11,0,0,1,2,47.55V25.83"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. How would I add the second copy in, can you show me how? How would I have it tracing over the second one?

Comment: How would I add in the darker triangle underneath it? How would that be written into the code?

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it up a little here. https://jsfiddle.net/8kLp5hyw/6/

Comment: A little problem with your second example is that the black triangle's anti-aliased edges shine from under cyan triangle's anti-aliased edges. In production, one probably shouldn't paint it like that, at least not with these colors. On the other hand, Mandy's fiddle seems fine with the same technique.

Comment: @EugeneRyabtsev How would you have written it differently?

Comment: @MandyEvans Most people would not notice that.  It's just a side-effect of the antialiasing that helps make the edges of things look smooth.  In the original, it is especially not noticeable because of the dark background.  If your version uses different colours, and it bothers you, you can make the rear one thinner by giving it a smaller `stroke-width`.